# Displaying Evernote Notes in Angular 2 - Sanitizing HTML stripped some content

Tags: html, angular, xss, evernote

Currently I have it set up so my Notes in evernote can be displayed on a website for content, but they don't show the way they should. I can't figure out how to get it to just display the way I try. Pictures don't show, links, videos, it all gets stripped out and says

```
WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).
```

I understand to prevent xss attacks they've done this to me, but how to I stop it??

Currently I'm using this in the HTML template

```
<div [innerHTML]="note"></div>
```

where `note` is the string containing my ENML.

I'm just not sure where to start. I am hoping there's a quick easy way to just make it display the way it displays in Evernote itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! I just did a pipe to mark the content as safe, like this [guy did here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/inserting-html-via-angular-2-use-of-domsanitizationservice-bypasssecuritytrusthtml/62562/2):D